# How can I tell if my variable is discrete or continuous?

Tags: continuous-data, discrete-data

```
> trees
   Girth Height Volume
1    8.3     70   10.3                   
2    8.6     65   10.3
3    8.8     63   10.2
4   10.5     72   16.4
5   10.7     81   18.8
6   10.8     83   19.7
7   11.0     66   15.6
8   11.0     75   18.2
9   11.1     80   22.6
10  11.2     75   19.9
11  11.3     79   24.2
12  11.4     76   21.0
13  11.4     76   21.4
14  11.7     69   21.3
15  12.0     75   19.1
16  12.9     74   22.2
17  12.9     85   33.8
18  13.3     86   27.4
19  13.7     71   25.7
```

I would like to know how to tell if each of my variables is discrete or continuous.

Comment: Have you performed some basic search on the definitions of discrete and continuous variables?

Comment: If so then are girth, height, and volume discrete or continuous?

Comment: Maybe if you stare at a living tree long enough you will see it leap from one level to another of the possible sizes and shapes it can have. :-)

Answer (score 1):

All data are measured with finite precision, so all data is technically discrete (whether or not the process from which the data arise is discrete or continuous). However, a lot of data is *precise enough* to be modeled as continuous.

I would treat yours at continuous.

Comment: Your first line contradicts Stevens' original definition of measurement types.  The definition does not rely on precision but on *groups of transformations* of the values that preserve meaningful relationships among them.

Comment: I should say, all data can be *modeled* as discrete. If a thermometer only measures temperature to 1/10 of a degree, then every 1/10 of a degree would be a value in a discrete variable.

Comment: You can find [Stevens' paper on the Web.](http://www.mpopa.ro/statistica_licenta/Stevens_Measurement.pdf)  It's worth reading.